# Tracking user activity

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to write MVC to log/track any user activity. 
Also I have psql db for project and separate mongodb for tracking.

Is there any embedded functions in RoR to log all CRUD actions??

Thank you for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041823/gem-to-track-user-activity looks similar.

Comment: I dont need a gem, I need some logics to track CRUD actions

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I haven't implemented this functionality directly, you maybe want to check out [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity):

[image]

It seems to use the [`public activity`](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity) gem

--

**Non-Gem**

If you wanted to implement this functionality *without* a gem, you may wish to use a callback in the `ApplicationController`:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :set_options, only: [:your, :actions]

   def set_options
       Activity.create({user_id: current_user.id, action: action_name})
   end
end

#app/models/activity.rb
Class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

#activities
id | user_id | action | information | etc | created_at | updated_at
```